# Fix JSON Output from API

Tags: python, json, python-requests

So I've got this API that I'm iterating through using python. I'm very much a beginner so I'm sort've stumbling around all this stuff.

Because I'm appending the data of each page that I get to the end of a JSOn file, the data is coming out like below:

```
[{"example":true, "testing":34, "html":"example sentence.</div><div><br></div><div>Example sentence"},{"example":true, "testing":34, "html":"example sentence.</div><div><br></div><div>Example sentence"}]
[{"example":true, "testing":34, "html":"example sentence.</div><div><br></div><div>Example sentence"},{"example":true, "testing":34, "html":"example sentence.</div><div><br></div><div>Example sentence"}]
[{"example":true, "testing":34, "html":"example sentence.</div><div><br></div><div>Example sentence"},{"example":true, "testing":34, "html":"example sentence.</div><div><br></div><div>Example sentence"}]
```

With square brackets around each data set of each page.

My goal at the end of this is to convert this data to a CSV file that will be easier to manipulate without coding. Given that, what would be the best way to clean up the data? I'll also post the code that I'm using to loop through the api requests just in case I'm doing something wrong there too.

```
pnum = 1
while pnum <4:
    querystring = {"q":"A","pageNumber":pnum,"pageSize":"2"}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(response.text, file=open("output_test.json", "a"))
    print (pnum)
    pnum = pnum + 1
    if response.text == '[]':
        break
print('Done!')
```

Much appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file before you loop **(1)**, then accumulate all objects **(2)**, then dump the list out to the file after the loop of requests **(3)**

Should create a single file that you can parse with other JSON tools

```
import json

with open("output_test.json", "w") as f:  # (1)
    pages = []
    for pnum in range(1, 5):
        print (pnum)
        querystring = {"q":"A","pageNumber":pnum,"pageSize":"2"}
        req = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        resp = req.json()
        if not resp:
            break
        for x in resp:  # assuming this is a list object
            pages.append(x)  # (2)

    json.dump(pages, f)  # (3)

print('Done!')
```

Personally, I think JSON files are more easily parsable than CSV

Comment: Ah awesome, thanks man. 2 questions if you have the time answer:

1. How would I go about continuing the loop until the resp is empty? is it just 'while True'?
2. In what way do you think it's easier to parse? definitely think I need to learn a bit more about JSON.

Comment: You could do a while True, but I would check if the request comes back with a 404 status code, then break the loop there. Or find another way to know when there are no pages left... And JSON can have nested structures and it's much easier to reason about for parsing in any other code compared to poorly formatted CSV. The only reason I would use CSV is if I used Excel, which is almost never